# How to pass properties from One controller to another in ember without involving route's setupController?

Tags: ember.js, model, controller, ember-cli, query-string

How to pass properties from One controller to another in ember without involving route's setupController

Comment: why do you want to do this?
but there is https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.4/classes/Route/methods/controllerFor?anchor=controllerFor

Comment: Personally, I like to use services for higher/app level communication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simplest cases you can inject one controller into another:

```
// app/controllers/signup.js

import Controller, { inject as controller } from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  login: controller('login'),

  signup() {
    // Do some requests to create new user

    // And then set properties on login controller
    this.login.set('formData', {
      email: this.get('formData.email'),
      password: this.get('formData.password'),
    });
  }
});
```

For something more complex, services are good.

Comment: very well said...perfect answer.

Comment: Worked! Thank You!

Comment: Although this does indeed work, it’s an older pattern that is generally disappearing. At some point I would expect it to be deprecated...

Comment: @acorncom what would you recommend instead? I use this approach quite often

Comment: @GennadyDogaev I’d recommend a service, as often when you need this type of between controller access it may grow over time. Doing it with two controllers doesn’t feel too bad. But then, you need that info in another controller, then in a component, then ... And soon you can have a mess 